# Execute command with ssh and prevent connection close (with Control + C)

Tags: ssh, remote

I am able to execute the command:
`cd /var/www/test; tail -f log/*.log;` in remote with ssh connection as:

```
ssh -t user@xx.yy.zz.aa "cd /var/www/test; tail -f log/*.log; exec $SHELL -l"
```

which works great.
But as soon as I press `Control + C` just to stop the command to do something else, it closes the connection saying

> Connection to xx.yy.zz.aa closed.

How to prevent this and stay connected even after pressing `Control + C`?

Comment: I second Hauke's answer: the Ctrl+C should be passed to the remote side and the remote shell should not terminate on Ctrl+C. [Tell us how to reproduce what you did](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): how you open the terminal that you run ssh from, what terminal it is, what `$SHELL` is, try to reproduce it without any configuration files and if you can't post the relevant files, etc.

Comment: I am using Mac OS's ITerm2 terminal and zsh as shell

Comment: I just tried running `ssh -t localhost 'exec /bin/zsh -l'` using iterm2 on a mac, and Ctrl-C works as expected--it interrupts commands running on the remote system, but not the remote shell itself or the ssh connection.

Comment: @Kenster Have you tried in remote?

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen. `ssh` should turn off signal generation in the terminal.

You can try to trap `SIGINT` in the shell which calls `ssh`

```
trap '' SIGINT
```

but the processes on the other side will not receive the signal then either.

You may also try to send a literal `^C` to `ssh` by pressing

```
^V^C
```

The `^V` is usually the "quoting" character for the terminal. I.e. instead of interpreting `^C` as to generate a signal it is just passed on literally.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you write the full command how it should be executed?

Comment: @MagePsycho Those are the full commands.

Comment: trap '' SIGINT && ssh -t user@xx.yy.zz.aa "cd /var/www/test; tail -f log/*.log; exec $SHELL -l" ?